# What purpose does node.js serve on SharePoint?

Tags: node.js, sharepoint, npm

I have read few posts on web on using Node.js on SharePoint. There is a SharePoint npm package too, but I couldn't find a genuine reason to what purpose does Node.js serve on SharePoint?. This question may sound vague but I couldn't find a reasonable answer even after searching a lot on the web.

Comment: So you could build node.js apps connected to a sharepoint farm.

Answer (score 1):

Well #node.js and #npm becomes the server to get the plugins and external libraries that are used to create the SharePoint new webparts with #yeoman using @microsoft/sharepoint repository. 
I've written a Primary overview of new #SharePoint from #microsoft #techsummit at #telaviv today. 
It can be useful to go over
https://grekai.wordpress.com/2016/12/08/sharepoint-with-all-the-new-toys/

Actually as we go Microsoft is switching to open source type of development very much alike MEAN stack for instance enabling you to use #Angular.js2 or #React.js  to implement your web parts. The problem its yet unstable as with every #Microsoft product just being thrown out there to see how it will survive :)

To your specific question the Node.js is required for you to be able to use npm and that is needed to get the libraries from the repositories to your local environment. And then you use yeoman to create already existing templates created by microsoft team.

Comment: Thanks. So Node can 'run', executes on Sharepoint? As in, it's an installed application running it's own server hosted by sharepoint? It can execute automation from there? Is this possible.

Answer (score -1):

nodejs could be used in theory as Provider Hosted App.

[Updated Aug 2018]
Well this question is over. TODAY if you want to code custom SharePoint WebParts you need to KNOW nodejs, npm, gulp, webpack, TypeScript (optional, but almost all examples from PnP SharePoint group are done with it)

Answer (score -2):

Say you run your node.js code and want to upload the results to sharepoint. For example, you can has node.js code that monitors various parts of your app. With the deftness of js then you can most quickly write deep unit tests and functional tests which tie together the use of multiple webservices. Then use a test framework like mocha and then upload that to sp. Well, I have yet to get that part working. Security issues and nobody has yet posted how to do it in node.js from within a corporate environment; there are pages on how to do it to the m$ft pub sharepoint cloud.